# i keep getting this error './a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tags: c

I was writing a piece of code that was supposed to do this:

> Write a function that given a natural number computes the value
> resulting from the digits of its decimal representation when
> interpreted as a hexadecimal number. Example: f(312) = 3 * 256 + 1 *
> 16 + 2 = 786 Hint: use the same recursive decomposition, but when
> reconstructing the number, use the new base (16).

the problem is I keep getting the error:

> ./a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int pwr(int x,int n){
    if (n==1){
        return n;
    }
    return x*pwr(x,n-1);
}

int countdigits(int nr){
    int count=0;
    while (nr!=0){
        nr=nr/10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int basechange(int nr,int count,int x){
    if(count==x-1){
        return nr*pwr(16,count);
    }
   return basechange((nr/10)%10,count+1,x)*pwr(16,count);
}

int main(){
    int nr = 312;
    int x = countdigits(nr);
    int count=0;
    printf("%d\n",basechange(nr,count,x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens when you call `pwr(16, 0)`?

Comment: Also, not related to your segfault, but consider... what should the value of `pwr(x, 1)` be? And what are you actually returning?